# Error while opening a Contact in CMS

Tags: audience-manager

After adding a new extended detail for Contacts, I am getting an error while opening the Contacts.

Steps I followed for creating a new custom contact extended field:

1. Updated `CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS` and `IMPORT_CONTACTS` tables in
   `cm_email` database
2. Updated `CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS` table in `submgmt` database
3. Added new Contact Detail In `OutboundEmail.xml`

> Error :The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Did you restart the services after your changes, or even tried rebooting the entire server?

Comment: I have restarted all the Tridion services. Do i need to restart the server?

Answer (score 2):

The list of Extended Details is heavily cached (since it's used very often). 
So after changing the fields you'll want to restart the application pool in IIS (or just do an IISReset) and restart the Tridion Content Manager Service Host service too.

That should solve the issue. If not, you might have missed a step when adding the field.

Comment: It worked after restarting the server. Thanks.